# Using Interlocked.Decrement inside If condition, could it cause any Concurrency Issue?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, .net-3.5

I am creating a custom CountdownWaitHandle class it has the following method:

```
public void Signal()
{
    if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref threadsInstances) <= 0)
    {
        mre.Set();
    }
}
```

mre is a instance of ManualResetEvent class and I use this class to block the current thread and wait to all threads complete his work and each thread when finish his work or  occurred an exception call Signal() method.

**So my question if the return value of Interlock.Decrement and condition(<=0) could cause any Concurrency Issue inside if condition?** or I have to use a lock statement for the if condition and if body instead of Interlock like as example above:

```
 lock(_lock)
   {
        if (--threadsInstances <= 0)
        {
            mre.Set();
        }   
   }
```

Note:I am using 3.5 net.

Complete code:

```
 public class CountdownWaitHandle : WaitHandle
    {    
        private int threadsInstances = 0;            
        private ManualResetEvent mre;    
        private readonly object threadsyncAccess = new object();

        public CountdownWaitHandle(int initialCount)
        {
            threadsInstances = initialCount;
            mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        }

        public void AddCount()
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref threadsInstances);
        }

        public void Signal()
        {
            if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref threadsInstances) <= 0)
            {
               mre.Set();
            }
        }

        public override bool WaitOne()
        {
            return mre.WaitOne();
        }   

    }
```

In this example.
I am going to use my custom CountdownEvent class to download a large 
file using chunks for any Cloud Site. So each chunk after finish downloading his range bytes it release the resources or move to another Stream.

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
   {          

        CountdownWaitHandle customCountDown = new CountdownWaitHandle(0)               

                    while (i < 100)
                    {

                        SpecificWork work1  = new SpecificWork (startPosition, endPosition, customCountDown);
                        customCountDown.AddCount();                                                       
                        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(PerformTask, work1); //  after finish download it invokes to Signal method. 
                    }
                    customCountDown.WaitOne();
                }
```

Comment: To respond to this question, we must see the "other" part of the code, the `Wait()` part and the `Interlocked.Increment`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I cannot use CountdownEvent.cs(.net 4)  because I am using  .net 3.5.

Comment: "if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref threadsInstances) <= 0)" this line is not atomic. the decrement is atomic but then there is another step to check if less or equal 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Interlocked.Decrement` will work as intended in this sample, assuming you are calling `Interlocked.Increment` to raise the count above zero.

Of course, using [`CountdownEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent(v=vs.110).aspx) would be better than building your own synchronization object.